# In-App Purchase buying a Pro version from a Lite version

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a created a lite and Pro version iPhone app (Xcode 5.0.2)

In my lite version, I tested the lite version purchase and it returns the lite version product details no problem
In my pro version, I tested the pro version purchase and it returns the pro version product details no problem

However, in the lite version, I want the user to press a button to directly buy the pro version, but this returns:

> Invalid product id: com.xxx.h1Pro

I also deleted the app on my iPhone 4 from the Xcode 5 organizer window and re-installed the app. It seems to me my logic is wrong on how to buy an Pro version inside a Lite version app. I'd appreciate it if somebody could clarify what I need to do.

My settings:

```
Xcode 5.0.2 Lite target build Settings:Provisioning Profile: 
    iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.xxx.h01Lite

Lite-Info.plist: bundle identifier:
    com.xxx.h01Lite

itunes connect Lite version in-app purchase:Product Id: 
    com.xxx.h1Lite

Xcode 5.0.2 Pro target Build Settings:Provisioning Profile:
    iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.xxx.h01Pro

Pro-Info.plist:bundle identifier:
    com.xxx.h01Pro

itunes connect Pro version in-app purchases: Product Id: 
    com.xxx.h1Pro
```

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the in app purchases for the Pro version of the app from the Lite version of the app ? Are they two separate apps ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that - I am trying to retrieve the app purchase for the Pro version from the Lite version of the app and they are two separate apps

Comment: You can't. As in app purchases are linked to a specific app.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can buy an app from another app. You can link to the itunes page of your pro version and allow the user to buy it. Or you can have all features locked in your lite version and after the user buys an in-app purchase item, you can check and unlock all pro functionality.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I found an article that I will include below for buying in-app content for iO6 and above in a way that keeps the user within your app: "users can buy and download apps, music, books and other iTunes content without leaving your app"

Answer (score 1):

I found this link that will allow users to remain within my app while buying other itunes content

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios_6/changes_to_storekit/

In-App Content Display & Purchasing – users can buy and download apps, music, books and other iTunes content without leaving your app. You can also link to your own apps to promote purchasing or just encourage reviews and ratings.

Comment: This is an 'app' though not an In-App Purchase. This is different from what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, true, however, good for giving a better user experience and showing the user any other products you want to sell them

Comment: Stick an add in or info page .... Why have two apps, why not have 1 that's free and you can unlock features. This is a better user experience as you don't have to download 2 apps.

Answer (score 0):

You should register the pro version as a non-consumable product of your light version and handle everything within a single app.

Comment: Yes, that would be the fastest and most straightforward way to do it. However, I deliberately chose to have the lite and pro app as 2 separate apps to keep the lite version a small file size for fast download considering mobile bandwidth restrictions (I am using sound files for the content) and also to keep the purchased content separate so that the pro content cannot be hacked from the lite version